# How to create a curved border in the corner of a div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create this:

[image: Current State]

Currently, it's looking like this:

[image: Desired State]

I've been tweaking for a really long time and can't figure out how to get it to look exactly like the first picture.

Here is my code:

```
    <Wrapper>
      <DaysLeftWrapper>
      <GoldText>108</GoldText>
      <Text>Days Left</Text>
      </DaysLeftWrapper>
```

```
const DaysLeftWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: -13px;
  right: -13px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px solid white;
  background-color: grey;
`;
```

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 505px;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Text and gold text are just styled divs.

How can I make mine look more like the first picture?

Comment: Set `top` and `right` to -50%

Comment: @javedb was your question answered by some of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `border-radius` on your wrapper component. You could start with adding `border-radius: 8px` to the wrapper itself. Then tweak the value to whatever looks the best.

Answer (score 0):

Add border-radius for Wrapper

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    border-radius: 10px;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

play with **border-radius** a bit

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const styledBox1 = {
  width: '300px',
  height: '300px',
  background: '#2F2F2F',
  border: '2px solid #5B97F4'
}

const styledBox2 = {
  border: '2px solid #C24E2B',
  width: 'inherit',
  height: 'inherit',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
}

const styledBox3 = {
  flex: '0 0 150px',
  height: '150px',
  textAlign: 'right',
  background: '#333333',
  borderBottomLeftRadius: '100%',
  padding: '1rem 1rem 3rem 3rem'
}

const styledText1 = {
  color: '#D2B861',
  fontSize: '2rem'
}

const styledText2 = {
  color: '#BBBBBC',
  fontSize: '2rem'
}



const App = () => {


return <div style={styledBox1}>
  <div style={styledBox2}>
    <div style={styledBox3}>
      <div style={styledText1}>108</div>
      <div style={styledText2}>Days left</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-ui-lab-umd@4.0.0-alpha.32/material-ui-lab.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```